# Will history of a domain affect rankings for new site?

Tags: seo, google, domains, search-engine-indexing, ranking

Bought the domain and initially parked the domain. Google did not rank the domain because it was parked, it has however began to index in the last day or so. My question is will the fact that the site used to be a parked domain have any negative effect on the new site in terms of ranking.

Is Google for example likely to penalise the site based upon the domain history or will the history have no impact on the new site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Parked domains are common and Google knows this and accounts for it in the algorithm.  Once the domain is un-parked and real content published, you are treated as any new site would be.

The only time this may matter (and indirectly at that) is if you obtain a domain that was previously active and park that for a while.  Depending on how long it was parked and how it was indexed prior to your re-development of the domain you might see some residual effects from the original content in the new rankings.  If it remains parked for long enough Google should eventually de-index the original content and treat the new content as a blank slate. But I confess that I have never really tested this personally so I am unsure what the exact time period would be.